# Android ListView selector

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a ListView in my application with following properties:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

But I can not see the selector on screen. I need a visible selector, how it is possible to make the selector visible and working??
And the same in "touch mode"?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/..."
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
            android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on touch. I use an emulator and nothing happening when I click the row on the ListView. But the View became whole gray when I am touching DPAD.

Comment: That is weird. It's getting gray through DPAD means that the selector is working. Which means that the ListView is not responding to the touch. I hope you have not put the ListView inside a ScrollView, have you ?

Comment: The ListView is inside the root LinearLayout.  Selector doesn't work even for DPAD because the whole View became gray, no rows visible, it is unexpected and undesirable.

Comment: Well, remove android:focusableInTouchMode="true" from the xml and try again.. ?